# Display Firebase data inside a spinner

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, spinner

I'm learning Kotlin, I have an Activity with a spinner and a textField, I'm able to download the data from Firebase. The problem I'm having is when I'm displaying the data inside the spinner, I see all objects in each child. How can I display just one? in my case I want to display itemName only. Here is my code and how my DB is structured:

```
    class MainActivity(val i: Int) : AppCompatActivity() {

    var labelText: TextView? = null
    var spinnerItems: Spinner? = null
    private val items = arrayListOf<Items>()
    lateinit var itemDbRef: CollectionReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        labelText = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        spinnerItems = findViewById(R.id.mySpinner)
        itemDbRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(ITEM_REF)
        getItems()
    }

    fun getItems() {
        itemDbRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
            for (document in snapshot.documents) {
                val data = document.data
                val itemName = data!![ITEM_NAME] as String
                val itemCode = data[ITEM_CODE] as String

                val newItemList = Items(itemName, itemCode)

                items.add(newItemList)
                println(newItemList)

            }

            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items.map { it.itemName })

            //   I need to display the name only
            spinnerItems?.adapter = arrayAdapter

            spinnerItems?.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>, view: View, i: Int, l: Long) {
                    val name = items[i].itemName
                    labelText?.text = "$name"
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            }
        }
    }

    fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
}
```

**Class**

```
data class Items constructor(
        val itemName: String, val itemCode: String
)
```

**Firebase DB**

```
collection/AutoID/itemCode: "item1"
                  itemName: "item2"

collection/AutoID/itemCode: "item3"
                  itemName: "item4"
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is items?.

Comment: an array:    private val items = arrayListOf<Items>()   Thank you!

Comment: do `private val items = arrayListOf<String>() items.add(newItemList.itemName)`

Comment: i get an instantiation error: Class has no zero argument constructor. I updated my original post with the entire code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this below

```
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items.map {it.itemName})
```

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. This: items.filter { it.itemName } requires a boolean and i'm adding a string. I even tried this: items.filter { it.itemName == true.toString() } and it does not display anything and i do not get any errors.

Comment: @Eddie sorry for my mistake, should use `map` instead of `filter`, I updated my answer, please give it a try